# MongoDb: Match value on foreign collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the collection USER:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d64d2bf48dd17387d77d27a"),
    "name" : "John",
    "notifications" : {
        "email" : false,
        "sms" : true
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da9586911e192081ee1c6be"),
    "name" : "Mary",
    "notifications" : {
        "email" : false,
        "sms" : false
    }
}
```

And this other collection ALERT:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d54f04dbe5e6275e53a551e"),
    "active" : true,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5d64d2bf48dd17387d77d27a")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d54f04dbe5e6275e53a551f"),
    "active" : false,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5d64d2bf48dd17387d77d27a")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d54f04dbe5e6275e53a552e"),
    "active" : true,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5da9586911e192081ee1c6be")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d54f04dbe5e6275e53a552f"),
    "active" : true,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5da9586911e192081ee1c6be")
}
```

I want a MongoDB query that lists the documents on collection ALERT that have property "active" as TRUE and whose matching USER has element "sms" on property "notifications" as TRUE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Uncorelated sub queries in $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

- `$match` to get the `"notifications.sms": true`
- `$lookup`to join two collections. We are assigning `uId = _id` from USER collection. Inside the `pipeline`, we use `$match` to find the `active :true`, and `_id=uId`

here is the script

```
db.USER.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "notifications.sms": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ALERT",
      "let": {
        uId: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                active: true
              },
              {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user_id",
                    "$$uId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joinAlert"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kdgaHU5ET2O)**